# Android - Record video at high quality

Tags: android, video-recording

I try the following code but I only get very poor quality compared to other apps in google play store. Any suggestions?

```
private void initRecorder(final String path) {
        videoFile = path;
        try {
            // Solves a -9 return bug in some Android versions
            camera.lock();
            camera.unlock();    
            recorder.setCamera(camera);
            recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(0, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P));
            recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
            recorder.setOutputFile(videoFile);
            recorder.setMaxDuration((int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(2));

            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showDialog(NO_VIDEO);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showDialog(NO_VIDEO);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            showDialog(NO_VIDEO);
        }

    }
```

## Another attemp

```
            recorder.reset();
            recorder.setCamera(camera);
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
//            recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
            recorder.setOutputFile(videoFile);
```

But im getting IlegalStateException when I use `recorder.start()`

Comment: You might confirm whether your device supports that profile, rather than blindly calling `setProfile()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think it does. Im testing with nexus 7 2013, and Samsung Galaxy tab 4.

Comment: Instead of just setting a specific profile value why don't you set it to CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH and also look at this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-video

Comment: I'm wondering what is causing you not to get the desired quality: is the recorded resolution different, or is it just a low bitrate? I have an open source camera recording library which does this. Does it work for the sample app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jmolsmobile.landscapevideocapture_sample The source code can be found here: https://github.com/JeroenMols/LandscapeVideoCamera/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/jmolsmobile/landscapevideocapture/recorder/VideoRecorder.java

Comment: Had something similar, try `recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264))`
or H263, anyway play around with the VideoEncoders you have there, one of them should fix it.

Comment: @AnkushSharma I have tried the settings which are recommended in developer.android and it's even worst. I get worst results using CamcorderProfile.HIGH than CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P.

Comment: Thanks you @jmols I will try your app.